# Redirect all pages to subfolder except blog in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect my all website (that developed on wordpress) links to a sub-folder like http://mywebsite.com/ to http://mywebsite.com/new/,  but http://mywebsite.com/blog/ , this should work as previously and in address bar it should not change.

I tried to add these lines in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase / 


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(blog)(/.*)? 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/$1 [L]
```

It is redirecting my all page to sub-folder but with blog it is redirecting to 404 page.

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

`REQUEST_URI` string starts with a leading slash. You need to put a slash before `(blog)(/.*)?` in your condition pattern.

Try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(blog)(/.*)?
```

Comment: Now, It is redirecting back to home page view.